# Release Managment Client failed on startup

Tags: .net, release-management, ms-release-management

I am using Microsoft Release Management Client for Visual Studio 2013. But it failed to start with the following 2 errors in event log:

Error 1:

> Faulting application name: ReleaseManagementConsole.exe, version:
>   12.0.21031.1, time stamp: 0x5272753c
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16864, time
>   stamp: 0x531d2be6
>
> Exception code: 0xe0434352
>
> Fault offset: 0x00010f22
>
> Faulting process id: 0x1108
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x01cfb539f264950b
>
> Faulting application path: D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 12.0\Release Management\bin\ReleaseManagementConsole.exe
>
> Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
>
> Report Id: 302cacba-212d-11e4-941f-001018ccb4a7
>
> Faulting package full name:
>
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

Error 2:

> Application: ReleaseManagementConsole.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.MissingFieldException
>
> Stack:    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Release.Console.App.OnStartup(System.Windows.StartupEventArgs)
>   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(System.Object)...

I am using Windows Server 2012 + Visual Studio 2013.

Anyone saw such issue before?

Comment: Did you run as admin? Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same problem a couple of times where Release Management was working then stopped. Both times turned out it was something wrong with my user profile information - I managed to sort out the problem by deleting all the files from:

```
C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\ReleaseManagementConsole._StrongName_x5pjssdhilxecxumty4fc2wj50dqoakc\12.0.0.0
```

Obviously the path won't be exactly like mine but you should be able to find it.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem with Release Management 2015, and deleting the file _user.config_ from _C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\ReleaseManagementConso‌​le._StrongName_x5pjssdhilxecxumty4fc2wj50dqoakc\14.0.0.0_ fixed it.